# How make my ul style only apply to one class

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-lists

I already make my style for `ul` and `li` and was working OK.

On the right side there is a partial view and is align with everything.

[image]

But now I realized was affecting other `ul li` in different area. 
So I add a class `.menuHeader`.

```
    .menuHeader ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .menuHeader li {
        float: left;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        .menuHeader li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            .menuHeader  li a:hover:not(.active) {
                background-color: #B0B0B0;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```

The normal links still work ok.

```
<ul class="menuHeader">
    <li class="menuHeader">@Html.ActionLink("Main", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = activeHome })</li>
    <li class="menuHeader">@Html.ActionLink("Tracker", "Index", "Tree", null, new { @class = activeTracker })</li>
    <li class="menuHeader">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new { @class = activeContact })</li>
    <li class="menuHeader">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = activeAbout })</li>
```

But for the partial view isnt and also appear the dot for the item list. So looks like I need define some other attributes there. Any idea what is missing?

[image]

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<ul class="menuHeader">
    <li id="login_area1" class="menuHeader">
        @Html.ActionLink(strHello, "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>
    <li class="menuHeader">
        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" id="logoutLink" style="color:red">
            Log off
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Logout-icon-door.png")">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

Comment: list-style: none on the li... also notice, the you should do .menuHeader and .menuHeader li... your are applying the same style for the ul and li which is weird...

Comment: @andresmijares25 But .`menuHeader ul`  already have it. Doesnt LI inherited from UL ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: You don't have `.menuHeader ul` element. It should be `ul.menuHeader` because the class is on the `ul` and not on the parent of `ul`. Regarding the question about *partial view*, I don't even understand what the problem is.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you are not...  .menuHeader ul... is doing nothing in your code, remove the ul or ul.menuHeader...

Comment: @Harry I add the `list-style: none` to the `LI` and now work OK, the partial view is also fixed. But now Im confused. Can you post as answer how you think should be the correct CSS? My strong isnt CSS and is already working but would like to learn more.

Comment: @Harry What you mean I dont have `.menuHeader ul` ?? My understanding is I use the class selector to identify the class and then  select the element I want?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't recommend adding the `list-style: none` alone to the `li` because there are other properties specified for the `ul` (like `background-color`, `margin`, `padding` etc) which won't work if the selector is left as-is (that is as `.menuHeader ul`). Although the `list-style: none` on `li` works for you. Can you let me know what happens when you change the first selector to `ul.menuHeader`. I would prefer giving an answer with that idea than the other.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza No it doesn't work that way. When you use `.menuHeader ul` it means select the `ul` which is the child of another element with `class='menuHeader'` and not select the `ul` with `class='menuHeader'`.

Comment: @Harry Yes `ul.menuHeader` work and doesnt have to include `list-style` on the li. Looks like I understand it wrong. `.class li` mean child LI's from a `.class`

Comment: Yes, the last statement of yours is correct. I am not posting an answer because there is already one on similar lines. Happy that it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks @Harry When I start I have `UL` and `LI` in my css,  And that should change to `.menuHeader and .menuHeader LI`.... The error was creating `.menuHeader UL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  shouldn't have the same class for `ul` and `li`

plus this:  `.menuHeader ul {` is saying that a parent will have a class `.menuHeader` having a ul as child, which is not what you have in your code.

Should be just `.menuHeader`

```css
.menuHeader {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}
.menuHeader li {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menuHeader li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menuHeader li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #B0B0B0;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuHeader">
  <li class="menuHeaderItem">
    <a class="active" href="#">asdas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuHeaderItem">
    <a href="#">asdas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuHeaderItem">
    <a href="#">asdasda</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menuHeaderItem">
    <a href="#">asdasda</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That make sense. But in this case I dont need define `menuHeaderItem` They will get the style from `menuHeader` because the `LI` are child from a  `menuHeader` class isnt?

Comment: Exactly, just to change the class for the demo